# WinRT XAML StoryBoard is missing

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml

I am getting the following when I type `<StoryBoard>` in XAML:

> StoryBoard not supported in a Windows App Project.

I started the project as follow:

> New Project > Templates > Visual C# > Windows > Windows 8 > Windows >
>   Blank App (Windows 8.1)

Here is the MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page
    x:Class="TestApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TestApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <StoryBoard></StoryBoard>
    </Grid>
```

First intellisense does not show StoryBoard and when I added the tag anyway the IDE shows line below the tags indicating that the tag is not supported.

Do I need to add an external reference?

Comment: This really doesn't tell us much. When you type what in XAML? Do you have a way to reproduce?

Comment: in MainPage.xaml between <Grid> </Grid>, I am trying to put <StoryBoard> tag for animation and I am getting a line under the tag, when I hover my mouse over it, I get the above mentioned message.

Comment: How are you putting Storyboard into your Grid? Show your xaml.

Comment: question been edited

Comment: Yea that's not how Storyboard works. Your error would be expected. You may want to revisit a tutorial. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storyboard can't be a child of a UIElemenent Collection:

```
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="BestStoryboardEver"></Storyboard>
    </Grid.Resources>
```

I recommend using blend for visual Studio to create storyboards. You can also add your storyboard to `<Page.Resources`.
I hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you. I needed it for hamburger menu in WinRT xaml but I ended up using grid with auto width and adding and clearing children.